# Horizontal scrolling in IOS WebView SELECT tag

Tags: ios, webview, html-select, wkwebview

I created a regular HTML with just a SELECT tag and some options. Load that inside a regular WKWebView and when I open it is impossible to select an item. Another strange behavior is that is possible to drag the scrollbar items horizontally. Take a look in the video: https://youtu.be/Ra4FNvmsWMs

Comment: I'm not using any css or javascript. It's an empty HTML file with just a regular SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a Pod module called SLPagingView. Removed it and the problem stopped.